# Como Criar DropDownList no ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Vocês poderiam me ajudar a criar um `DropDownList` no MVC4?

Tenho a classe `ProjetoFuncionario` que é uma classe associativa de `Projeto` e `Funcionario`.

Devo criar uma classe para o DropDown?

Estou tendo muitas dificuldades em criar uma `DropDownList`. Tem algum tutorial bom ou uma dica que vocês podem me dar?

Obrigada.

```
namespace Exercicio1.Models
{
    public class ProjetoFuncionario
    {
        public Projeto IdProjeto { get; set; }
        public Funcionario IdFuncionario { get; set; }

        public List<ProjetoFuncionario> listaProjetoFuncionario()
        {
            return new List<ProjetoFuncionario>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que vai aparecer no DropDown?

Comment: O Objetivo e pegar o IDProjeto e IDFuncionario e associar os dois para preenchimento de um form usando o dropdown.. nao sei se ficou mto claro

Comment: Ok, vou responder pra você.

Comment: Ok, agradeço mto pela ajuda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `DropDownList` exige um Id bem definido. Sua associação não possui este Id. Além disso, sua classe está bem fora do padrão. Vamos fazer alguns ajustes:

```
public class ProjetoFuncionario
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjetoFuncionarioId { get; set; }
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
    public virtual Funcionario Funcionario { get; set; }
}
```

Na convenção do Entity Framework, framework padrão para acesso a dados do MVC4, a convenção de nomes pede para que Id seja um sufixo, e não um prefixo, por isso mudei para `FuncionarioId`, `ProjetoId`, etc.

Outra coisa é que coloquei uma chave primária para a associação. Isso garante o funcionamento correto da `DropDown`.

Ainda, repare que existe as propriedades inteiras (que são as chaves que serão gravadas em banco) e as propriedades de navegação (as classes com o `virtual` na frente). Cada uma tem sua função, que não é a mesma. As classes `virtual` servem pro Entity Framework trazer os registros do banco automaticamente pra você.

Feito isso, o resto é simples. Possivelmente você precisará ter uma *Action* no *Controller* pra trazer isso pra você.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var projetosFuncionario = contexto.ProjetoFuncionarios.Where(pf => pf.FuncionarioId == 1);

    ViewBag.ProjetosFuncionario = projetosFuncionario.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Coloquei o retorno dentro de uma `ViewBag`. ViewBags são objetos dinâmicos usados para mandar informações adicionais para uma *View*.

Finalmente, chegamos na *View*. Para montar uma DropDown, use o Helper @Html do Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjetoFuncionarioId, 
    ((IEnumerable<ProjetoFuncionario>)ViewBag.ProjetosFuncionario).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = option.Projeto.Nome + ", " + option.Funcionario.Nome, 
        Value = option.ProjetoFuncionarioId,
        Selected = (Model != null) && (option.ProjetoFuncionarioId == Model.ProjetoFuncionarioId)
}), "Escolha uma opção...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: entendi mto bem.. era isso mesmo que eu precisava mas antes da prática, precisava de entender o processo. Só uma coisa no segundo bloco do código o que seria o "contexto" ? espero não ser tão ignorante, estou aprendendo a programar direito e com mvc de brinde rs

Comment: @ThamiresCunha O contexto é um objeto do tipo `DbContext`. É ele que traz os dados do banco de dados para a sua aplicação, sem a necessidade de você precisar escrever comandos em SQL.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Caso eu tivesse uma propriedade `public IEnumerable<CategoriaViewModel> Categorias = new List<CategoriaViewModel>();` (onde carrego todas a categorias) na minha _ViewModel_ como eu faria usar sua solução? Estou com dúvidas em como utilizar o `SelectListItem``.