# ASP.NET MVC - Mudar input para dropdown e popular com valores de tabela SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, razor, dropdown

Tenho uma view parcial (neste caso, uma daquelas Razor Pages) do tipo "Create" criada a partir de uma tabela no SQL Server (que se encontra guardada como entidade de um modelo na minha aplicação).

```
@model Candidaturas.Models.DadosPessoai


@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "DadosPessoais", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeColoquial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeColoquial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomeColoquial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nomes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nomes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nomes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Apelidos, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apelidos, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apelidos, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomePai, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomePai, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomePai, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeMae, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeMae, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomeMae, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NDI, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NDI, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NDI, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoDocID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TipoDocID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoDocID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genero, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nacionalidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nacionalidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nacionalidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistritoNatural, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DistritoNatural, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistritoNatural, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Concelho, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Concelho, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Concelho, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Freguesia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Freguesia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Freguesia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Morada, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Morada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Morada, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Localidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Localidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Localidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

No entanto, alguns dos campos aparecem como inputs de texto quando não é isso que pretendo. Por exemplo, tenho um input "Genero" que aparece como input de texto normal que gostaria de tornar numa dropdown list e popular com valores a partir de uma tabela SQL. Como não tenho muita experiência em ASP.NET (muito menos a lidar com Razor Pages), qual a melhor abordagem a seguir?

Comment: Você pode usar um `DropDownListFor` no lugar dos inputs, aqui tem uma resposta com um bom exemplo: [Como Criar DropDownList no ASP.NET MVC 4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40616/57220)

Comment: Tentei seguir esse exemplo mas obtive o seguinte erro:

O valor não pode ser nulo.
Nome do parâmetro: source

Comment: Acabei por resolver o erro ao criar a SelectListItem no backend.